# GLFW and glew linking errors with Visual Studios 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, opengl, linker, glut, glfw

To put it simply:

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _glfwSetWindowTitle referenced in function _main
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__glewInit@0 referenced in function _main
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__glewExperimental
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _glfwTerminate referenced in function _main
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _glfwOpenWindow referenced in function _main
....etc....
```

In linker->input->additional dependencies:

```
opengl32.lib
glfw.lib
glew32.lib
glu32.lib
```

I've been trying everything I can think of here and nothing's worked, so some of those might not even be necessary.

Then in additional library directories, I've got: `$(VSInstallDir)lib; $(Path)`, neither of which should be necessary. I've got the library files in there, and have also tried copying them to the project directory and every sub-directory, and still no dice. I'm grateful for any advice or insight!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you add the `#define GLFW_DLL`
I can reproducethe error when I added it.
If you want uses the DLL version of GLFW, you should add GLFWDLL.lib.
Check [GLFW 2.7.4 release notes](http://www.glfw.org/release-2.7.4.html).

Comment: I don't define GLFW_DLL, though I have tried using it that way, with the DLL, and including GLFWDLL.lib.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the issue with GLFW, but for GLEW I had to define GLEW_STATIC.

Go to Project->Properties->C/C++->Preprocessor, then under Preprocessor Definitions add GLEW_STATIC.

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue very similar to this. I could write the code in my entry point to use GLFW and GLEW to create a window, but as soon as I would abstract this in a separate document (ie app.hpp), and include it to my entry point, it would not compile despite the code being correct.

> error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__glewInit@0 referenced in function _main
>   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__glewExperimental

These two errors I got because somehow, GLEW was not being properly included to my project. What the actual issue was that the linker was not getting the proper documents it needed. Namely being that I used glew32s.dll and not glew32.dll.

The immediate fix was to stop using GLEW_STATIC and to use GLEW. I did the same steps as I list below, instead using glew32.dll instead of static GLEW, and it all worked fine for me.

Make sure that the includes for GLFW and GLEW were made in:

> Properties > C/C++ > General > Additional Include Directories

Then you need to link the libraries GLFW and GLEW in:

> Properties > Linker > General > Additional Library Directories

And of course, make sure you tell input what DLLs you want to use (both GLFW and GLEW in this case)

> Properties > Linker > Input > Additional Dependencies

Then you take both the GLFW and GLEW DLLs you just told added to the additional dependencies and stick them in the folder where you contain your entry point (main.cpp).

This fixed all of my issues-which essentially was a similar problem to yours.

Hope this solved your problem. Pay close attention to copying those DLL files to your folder containing the entry point-this is exactly where I fell short.

> opengl32.lib
>   glfw3.lib
>   glew32s.lib
>   glew32.lib